# Protobuf : WebApi -> JS - Decoded object is empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I would like to send an object from a `WebApi` controller to an Html page through an `Ajax` Request.

When I receive the object in JS, it's empty. But server-side the object isn't empty because when I look at the `byte[].length` it's greater than 0.

- Server-side, I use the [dll provided by Google](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Protobuf).
- JS side, I use the [ProtobufJS library](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js). This is my `.proto` file :

  ```
  syntax="proto3";

  message Container {
      repeated TestModel2 Models = 1;
  }

  message TestModel2 {
      string Property1 = 1;
      bool Property2 = 2;
      double Property3 = 3;
  }
  ```

  - Server code :

    ```
    var container = new Container();

    var model = new TestModel2
    {
        Property1 = "Test",
        Property2 = true,
        Property3 = 3.14
    };
    ```

    container.Models.Add(model);
  - Base64 data :

  > ChEKBFRlc3QQARkfhetRuB4JQA==

  - JS decoding :

    ```
    var ProtoBuf = dcodeIO.ProtoBuf;
    var xhr = ProtoBuf.Util.XHR();
    xhr.open(
        /* method */ "GET",
        /* file */ "/XXXX/Protobuf/GetProtoData",
        /* async */ true
    );
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onload = function (evt) {
        var testModelBuilder = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile(
            "URL_TO_PROTO_FILE",
            "Container.proto").build("Container");
        var msg = testModelBuilder.decode64(xhr.response); 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(msg, null, 4)); // Correctly decoded
    }
    xhr.send(null);
    ```
  - Result object in JS console :

    ```
    {
        "Models": []
    }
    ```
  - bytebuffer.js
  - protobuf.js v5.0.1

Comment: So your request is successful, only - the Object you receive is empty? Try running the request directly in the browser and seeing the output and then share your output with us :)

Comment: It seems that when the JS decode the message, the object is or empty or the decoding process can't succeed so i get the default state object

What do you mean by "running the request directly in the browser" ?

Comment: Okay if you're unsure if it is just empty or the decoding process isn't completing - remove the decoding process and just `console.log` the response. If its not empty there then we can go through the decoding process. We need to see error's because we can't debug for you. & I assumed that you're not authenticating headers on requests with keys so if so, you should be able to directly request it through the URL as see the absolute response your *AJAX* request would be getting - then work from there. That's assuming this API was built by you also.

Comment: When I `console.log` the response I obtain this `ArrayBuffer {}` So I suppose that the response is empty. But server-side, when I serialize my object in `byte[]`, the length is > 0 and I am able to deserialize it and its not empty. Plus, in the Chrome console the ajax response is `ChEKBFRlc3QQARkfhetRuB4JQA==`

Comment: I voted up so your question will be seen, I don't specialise in JavaScript so any client-side code, I'm useless. As long as you're receiving your Object and it contains something, I'm sure you'll get a solution if they take a look at these comments also. Good luck, you may want to bounty it because it is a in-depth question which most scan read. But again, I hope you find a solution!

Comment: Ok I understand. I suppose a dumb mistake in my code but can't figure out where. Anyway, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem by myself.

It was the client-side which was in fault.

- In fact the `xhr.response` is JSON format so it was between double quotes `"ChEKBFRlc3QQARkfhetRuB4JQA=="`. I had to JSON.parse my response.`enter code here`
- I removed the `xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";`

Here is my code now :

```
var ProtoBuf = dcodeIO.ProtoBuf;
var xhr = ProtoBuf.Util.XHR();
xhr.open(
    /* method */ "GET",
    /* file */ "/XXXX/Protobuf/GetProtoData",
    /* async */ true
);
// xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer"; <--- Removed
xhr.onload = function (evt) {
    var testModelBuilder = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile(
        "URL_TO_PROTO_FILE",
        "Container.proto").build("Container");
    var msg = testModelBuilder.decode64(JSON.parse(xhr.response)); <-- Parse the response in JSON format
    console.log(msg); // Correctly decoded
}
xhr.send(null);
```